# MATLAB: simultaneously append to multiple elements of a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, vectorization

I want to append an item to multiple elements of a cell array, at once, in a loop over the items (to be appended).  E.g.

```
nodes(nodesHere,1) = cellfun(@(x)[x items(i)], nodes(nodesHere,1),'UniformOutput',false);
```

The elements of `nodes` might be any array type.
Is there an equivalent way, relying only on indexing, rather than the relatively more expensive closure used above?

Comment: You can loop instead of running `cellfun`, which may save you some overhead. But that's about it.

Comment: OK, thanks.  The `for` loop version also greatly simplifies things if the item itself is an array, so that e.g. `items(nodesHere)` have to be appended to matching `nodes(nodesHere)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
x = cell(1,5);
x(1:3) = num2cell([1, 2, 3]);
disp(x);
```

I know the code won't work for ANY type of array, but it would do the trick if you use mostly numeric data.

Comment: It needs to *append* a different number/matrix to each element of the cell array, across multiple iterations.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood you.